# OS: swap space, when is data stored in swap space?

Tags: operating-system, paging, page-fault

I understood the process of swapping but have a question about the swap space.

As far as I know, if I executes a program, the main memory fetches data from the disk because there is no data in cache and memory. Then what about swap space? Is swap space used only as a back-up storage when page swapping out is needed? or does the program place all of data to swap space when it is executed so that when there is a page fault, it swaps in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swapping has largely disappeared. However, M$ has recently reintroduced it to Windoze for certain processes.

In Swapping, the entire process is moved out of memory and stored on disk. The operating system uses swapping to make room in memory for other processes. In the days of 64K address spaces, transferring a process between memory and disk was not that time consuming.

Swapping has been replaced largely by PAGING whereby individual pages of memory are moved to secondary storage rather than the entire process.